# Fixed theta in line polar (radar) graph in animation - Plotly express

Tags: python, plotly

Is there a posibility to fix direction theta values (NW,SW,...etc.) and prevent them from changing positions?

Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.wind()
df = df.iloc[1:]
df['frameId'] = np.random.randint(1, 21, df.shape[0])
directionList = df['direction'].values.tolist()
fig = px.line_polar(df, r="frequency", theta=directionList, line_close=True,
                    color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r, animation_frame="frameId",)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason to use `df = df.iloc[1:]`?

Comment: Hey, I wanted to make the total number of rows divided by 21 without the rest. This is the only reason. Data is random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is in data preparation. Ensure that all combinations of *frameId* and *direction* exist in data frame used to build figure.

- generate all combinations as a dataframe `itertools.product()`
- right join this to data set.  This means there will be a row for every combination, where there was no source data *NaN* will be present
- additionally for good measure added sorting of data so that directions are correct clockwise

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import itertools
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.wind()
df = df.iloc[1:]
df['frameId'] = np.random.randint(1, 21, df.shape[0])

# clockwise order or direction
direction_map = {
    d: i
    for i, d in enumerate(
        "N, NNE, NE, ENE, E, ESE, SE, SSE, S, SSW, SW, WSW, W, WNW, NW, NNW".split(", ")
    )
}

# ensure all combinations of direction are available for every frame
# plus get order right...
df2 = df.merge(
    pd.DataFrame(
        itertools.product(df["frameId"].unique(), df["direction"].unique()),
        columns=["frameId", "direction"],
    ),
    on=["frameId", "direction"],
    how="right",
).pipe(
    lambda d: d.assign(order=d["direction"].map(direction_map)).sort_values(
        ["frameId", "order"]
    )
)

fig = px.line_polar(df2, r="frequency", theta="direction", line_close=True,
                    color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r, animation_frame="frameId",)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Interesting solution but it completely changes the closed curve plotted. I'm trying to find a solution modifying the layout for each frame.

Comment: can you better explain? this guarantees consistency between frames, but the frames are assigned randomly so you will get random data between frames

Comment: do you mean you do not want missing g value to be NaN but 0, so you always get a star rather than missing lines?  just add `df2 = df2.fillna(0)` before generating figure

Comment: Thanks Rob. Hell of a good job :) I will surely use it in my project.